# Why is insmod returning "killed" upon executing the code given in comments?

Tags: drivers

```
int *catch;

int start(void)
{

    alloc_chrdev_region(catch,0,1,"scull");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "The current process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\n",current->comm, current->pid);
    return 0;
}

void end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, Stupid World\n");
    unregister_chrdev_region(*catch,1);
}

module_init(start);
module_exit(end);
```

if I am trying to run the same code taking catch as only an integer and not as an pointer, it works fine.